# Building with autotools: AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS conflicts with ACLOCAL.AMFLAGS

Tags: android, c, autoconf, automake, libtool

Trying to build libwally-core C library for Android on Windows in Cygwin with supplied autotools scripts:

[libwally-core](https://github.com/ElementsProject/libwally-core)

After running

```
bash tools/build_android_libraries.sh
```

or

```
bash tools/autogen.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize:   error: AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([build-aux/m4]) conflicts with 
ACLOCAL.AMFLAGS=-I build-aux/m4
autoreconf-2.69: libtoolize failed with exit status: 1
```

I tried the following things to no avail:

- Re-saved all scripts with Unix line-endings (LF only)
- Commenting out "ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I tools/build-aux/m4" in Makefile.am

The error happens at the following place in libtool's source in libtoolize.in:

```
macrodir="$ac_macrodir"
test -z "$macrodir" && macrodir="$am_macrodir"

if test -n "$am_macrodir" && test -n "$ac_macrodir"; then
  test "$am_macrodir" = "$ac_macrodir" \
    || func_fatal_error "AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([$ac_macrodir]) conflicts with ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS=-I $am_macrodir."
fi
```

I assume that the above makes sure that AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR and value after "-I" in ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS are identical (checked for identical line endings with hex editor too). The values are identical in both configure.ac and Makefile.am. However, even if I comment out setting ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am, the error persits.

I would like to compile the library and generate libwallycore.so. Any insight would be much appreciated.